# Reading memory adresses from 16 bit PE

Tags: windows, delphi, portable-executable, 16-bit

I have PE file that was made with 16bit delphi. I spent all day trying to use WriteProcessMemory() on this file. It doesn't work. I can't find adresses in cheat engine nor tsearch. Peid says that file is not valid PE, I guess thats because of 16 bits?

Do you have any ideas how to read these adresses ?
I can post exe if needed.

Comment: I thought I accepted some - maybe I missclicked. Anyway - Fix'd

Comment: There is no such thing as "16-bit PE". Find NE format specs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi 16bit didn't make PE files. It made NE files... IOW, NE = "New Executable" and PE = "Portable Executable" NE files were introduced in Windows 32bit with the release of Windows NT 3.1 around '92 or '93.

It is not likely that you'll be able to read the memory of a running 16bit process from a 32bit process. This is because a 16bit application will run within a special subsystem that emulates the 16bit environment.

Comment: Hey! Thanks!
So I actually managed to read the adress from the emulator process and my program returns succes on writeprocessmemory. But ofcourse nothing happens :P My question is:
Should I write it to emulator or program ?

Comment: @zarcel - Alan's answer already has the answer to your comment. There's no program, only the subsystem. You won't find a process for a 16bit program on a 32bit system, ntvdm runs them in threads. You may (or not) get some hints for what you're trying to do [here](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0898/hood0898.aspx).